# Webgrid total row count using jQuery

Tags: jquery

Basically I am using an MVC architecture (.Net), where I have a model, a corresponding controller as well and a view page. In that view page I have a partial view which loads the webgrid where values are coming from data base. Now I want to delete records from the webgrid only (temporarily). It will not show the records but will not deleted from the database. I have done this part.

Now my webgrid is showing only the header part as I have deleted all items. Now how can I get the webgrid row count. Where I want to see - 0,

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var grid = $find('<%= this.WebDataGrid1.ClientID %>');

//get grid rows and call get_length method which returns exactly the rows count

var lenght = grid.get_rows().get_length();
```